# How can I hide the text behind the radiobuttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

For what I have now its almost working, but the only thing is that when I hide the item `item_35317` I also want the rest of the labels hidden (`Zelfde als bij 'Uw gegevens'` and `"Ander adres"`)

Note: I can't change anything in the HTML, I'm only allowed to change it with either `JS` or `CSS`

Maybe some one know how i can hide this

```js
$("input[name=item_35174][value='1']").prop('checked', true);

$("input[name='item_35174']").change(function() {
  $("label[for=item_35317], input[type=radio][name=item_35317]").toggle(this.value == "0");
  $("label[for=item_35175], input#item_35175").hide();
  $("label[for=item_35176], input#item_35176").hide();
  $("label[for=item_35177], input#item_35177").hide();

});
$("input[name='item_35174']:checked").change(); //trigger correct state onload

$("input[name='item_35317']").change(function() {
  $("label[for=item_35175], input#item_35175").toggle(this.value == "1");
  $("label[for=item_35176], input#item_35176").toggle(this.value == "1");
  $("label[for=item_35177], input#item_35177").toggle(this.value == "1");
});
$("input[name='item_35317']:checked").change(); //trigger correct state onload
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mx_form_row">
  <label for="item_35174">Naar luchthaven brengen: *</label>
  <div class="mx_form_input">
    <div class="mx_form_input_option">
      <input type="radio" name="item_35174" value="0" /> Ja
    </div>
    <div class="mx_form_input_option">
      <input type="radio" name="item_35174" value="1" /> Nee
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mx_form_label">Vul hier enkel de gegevens in van uw ophaaladres naar de luchthaven</div>
<div class="mx_form_spacer"></div>
<div class="mx_form_row">
  <label for="item_35317">Ophaaladres</label>
  <div class="mx_form_input">
    <div class="mx_form_input_option">
      <input type="radio" name="item_35317" value="0" /> Zelfde als bij &#039;Uw gegevens&#039;
    </div>
    <div class="mx_form_input_option">
      <input type="radio" name="item_35317" value="1" /> Ander adres
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mx_form_row">
  <label for="item_35175">Adres</label>
  <div class="mx_form_input">
    <input type="text" name="item_35175" id="item_35175" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mx_form_row">
  <label for="item_35176">Postcode</label>
  <div class="mx_form_input">
    <input type="text" name="item_35176" id="item_35176" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mx_form_row">
  <label for="item_35177">Woonplaats</label>
  <div class="mx_form_input">
    <input type="text" name="item_35177" id="item_35177" value="" />
```

Comment: why not use css: `.mx_form_input_option { font-size: 0; }`

Comment: all classes have the names "mx_form_input_option", then he will minimize all other forms also, but this is a part of a bigger form.

Comment: "rest of the labels hidden" but they are NOT labels they are text on the page as you have it here.

Comment: The whole form and website is live at: https://www.taxikeistad.nl/online-reserveren when you see there the source code, its a text behind a label and begint the input. The problem is this is a cms of some else where i can not make changes in the system at self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap what you call labels in a span and give them and the actual labels a class then use the context of the element to change the labels.

I used a custom event to handle the showhide of things.
I will add a bit more explanation when I get a bit more time.

EDIT: Regarding the custom event I randomly chose to call `hideShowMe`.  I pass this event some custom values ref: https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

To pass those: `$(this).trigger('hideShowMe', [isTrue, $showAssociates, $hideAssociates]);` then use them in the event handler: `function(event, isTrue, $showAssociates, $hideAssociates)`, this is ONE way to do this; there are several others such as classes on elements or data attributes.

Then I used the `.toggle()` which has a boolean value passed to show when true and hide when false.
Then, I find the labels in the parent "row" container `$showAssociates.closest('.mx_form_row').find('.toggle-label').toggle(isTrue);` and toggle them based on the boolean value.

Note I also did an initial `trigger()` of the change event to set initial state of the display:

```
$("input[name='item_35174']:checked") // one element selector
.add("input[name='item_35317']:checked")  // .add() adds a second element selector
.trigger('change'); // trigger the change event
```

Regarding the two selectors to gather references to elements:

```
let $showAssociates = $("label[for=item_35317],input[type=radio][name=item_35317]");
```

is effectively the same as

```
let $showAssociates = $("label[for=item_35317]")
    .add("input[type=radio][name=item_35317]");
```

```js
// this wraps the text after the input in a span so we can better work with that.
$('.mx_form_input_option input').each(function() {
  $(this.nextSibling).wrap('<span class="toggle-label"></span>');
});

$("input[name=item_35174][value='1']").prop('checked', true);

//custom event, add to anything we want to target
$("input[name='item_35174']")
  .add("input[name='item_35317']")
  .on('hideShowMe', function(event, isTrue, $showAssociates, $hideAssociates) {
    $showAssociates.toggle(isTrue);
    $hideAssociates.toggle(false);
    $showAssociates.closest('.mx_form_row').find('.toggle-label').toggle(isTrue);
  });

$("input[name='item_35174']").on('change', function() {
  const isTrue = this.value == "0";
  let $showAssociates = $("label[for=item_35317], input[type=radio][name=item_35317]");
  let $hideAssociates =
    $("label[for=item_35175], #item_35175")
    .add("label[for=item_35176], #item_35176")
    .add("label[for=item_35177], #item_35177");
  $(this).trigger('hideShowMe', [isTrue, $showAssociates, $hideAssociates]);
  $('input[type=radio][name=item_35317]:checked').trigger('change');
});

$("input[name='item_35317']").on('change', function() {
  const isTrue = this.value == "1";
  let $showAssociates = $("label[for=item_35175], input#item_35175")
    .add("label[for=item_35176], input#item_35176")
    .add("label[for=item_35177], input#item_35177");
  let $hideAssociates = $('idonotexist');
  $(this).trigger('hideShowMe', [isTrue, $showAssociates, $hideAssociates]);
});
$("input[name='item_35174']:checked")
  .add("input[name='item_35317']:checked")
  .trigger('change'); //trigger correct state onload
```

```css
.toggle-label {
  border: solid #00ff00 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mx_form_row">
  <label for="item_35174">Naar luchthaven brengen: *</label>
  <div class="mx_form_input">
    <div class="mx_form_input_option">
      <input type="radio" name="item_35174" value="0" /> Ja
    </div>
    <div class="mx_form_input_option">
      <input type="radio" name="item_35174" value="1" /> Nee
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mx_form_label">Vul hier enkel de gegevens in van uw ophaaladres naar de luchthaven</div>
<div class="mx_form_spacer"></div>
<div class="mx_form_row">
  <label for="item_35317">Ophaaladres</label>
  <div class="mx_form_input">
    <div class="mx_form_input_option">
      <input type="radio" name="item_35317" value="0" />Zelfde als bij &#039;Uw gegevens&#039;
    </div>
    <div class="mx_form_input_option">
      <input type="radio" name="item_35317" value="1" />Ander adres
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mx_form_row">
  <label for="item_35175">Adres</label>
  <div class="mx_form_input">
    <input type="text" name="item_35175" id="item_35175" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mx_form_row">
  <label for="item_35176">Postcode</label>
  <div class="mx_form_input">
    <input type="text" name="item_35176" id="item_35176" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mx_form_row">
  <label for="item_35177">Woonplaats</label>
  <div class="mx_form_input">
    <input type="text" name="item_35177" id="item_35177" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a yellow bullut at line 12 in the first code :(
https://jsfiddle.net/hxLnwupt/

Comment: there are two semi colon thats why there is a yellow bullet at line 12

Comment: @Smileface FWIW that fiddle is NOT the same as this code however - the HTML differs.  I did not try to debug but this works whereas the fiddle does not.

Comment: With some additional classes this can probably be reduced and made more DRY also.

Comment: `TypeError: $hideAssociates is null` - Ja / Ander adres

Comment: @KScandrett It's not an error I did not have any to hide so I set it to null `let $hideAssociates = null;` as I said this can be made more DRY perhaps by adding a class or data attributes etc.

Comment: I see that you have add: "<span class="toggle-label"> Zelfde als bij &#039;Uw gegevens&#039;</span>", but i can not add a class in the CMS, thats the whole problem. When i shall use a different CMS or it was a own website, i know that i could be more options. but i can nothing change in the html, i can only made the bypass in the scripts

Comment: I think I can fix that via small bit of script; let me try that and do an update

Comment: I put an ugly green border around the labels just to show it was wrapped

Comment: YES this is what i mean, i see the code and i dont know how you do it, but it's working in jsfiddle.. but i have now also a problem that Jqueri total not working anymore.

Comment: There is no total here that I see, perhaps another question.  This does not really "require" jQuery but as to the "how" jQuery is based on JavaScript with specific features such as chaining, using selectors which can now be done with things like `.querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` etc. so understanding JavaScript well is key perhaps moving forward.  SOME of this would be better (like the wrap) done in the source HTML page - whatever generates that.

Comment: No I have your script not test on the live website. But I'm now stuck in the live website self. I don't know what there is changed but I can not much now.

Comment: Without knowing much about what is in play things like `item_35317` seem like they will/might change - that can be handled with some "creative" code but knowing the hide/show pairs might get untenable to maintain over time.